# Excel and MapQuest API

Tags: xml, excel, vba, api, mapquest

MapQuest has changed their XML file and I'm no longer able to retrieve the distance and the time.

My VBA script is hung up on the following:

```
Private Sub GetDistance_MapQuest(ByVal startFrom As String, ByVal endAt As String, ByRef refMiles As Double, ByRef refHours As Double)

Dim url         As String
Dim resp        As String

Dim req         As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim xdoc        As MSXML2.DOMDocument

url = "http://www.open.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key=Fmjtd%7Cluua2q61n5%2C8g%3Do5-hzzll&drivingStyle=2&callback=renderAdvancedNarrative&ambiguities=ignore&avoidTimedConditions=false&doReverseGeocode=true&outFormat=xml&routeType=fastest&timeType=1&enhancedNarrative=false&shapeFormat=raw&generalize=0&locale=en_US&unit=m"
url = url & "&from=" & Replace(Trim(startFrom), " ", "%20")
url = url & "&to=" & Replace(Trim(endAt), " ", "%20")

Set req = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
req.Open "GET", url, False
req.send

resp = req.responseText

Set xdoc = req.responseXML

refMiles = CSng(xdoc.SelectSingleNode("response / route / distance").Text)
refHours = CLng(xdoc.SelectSingleNode("response / route / time").Text) / 60 / 60
```

The script stops on

`req.send`

and says the system cannot locate the resource specified. It worked previously. Does anyone have an idea how I can correct this?

Comment: Examine the new format and edit your code accordingly?  You've not included and "old" or "new" sample data, so it's difficult to suggest anything concrete here.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, MapQuest has not changed the XML response format for the Directions API Web Service. Are you sure you are using the correct AppKey with the correct service?  If you are using t[he Free & Open (Open Data) version of the Directions API](http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/), are you calling http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key= ?

Comment: I am calling  url = "http://www.open.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key=Fmjtd%7Cluurn1u7n1%2C7w%3Do5-9wy214&drivingStyle=2&callback=renderAdvancedNarrative&ambiguities=ignore&avoidTimedConditions=false&doReverseGeocode=true&outFormat=xml&routeType=fastest&timeType=1&enhancedNarrative=false&shapeFormat=raw&generalize=0&locale=en_US&unit=m"